# Subviews has a delegates, bad design?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

Here's the setup of a basic poker game.

`PokerViewController` has a subview called `PokerTableView`. The latter has a bunch of subviews called `CardView`s.

I'm trying to be a good programmer and following the basic MVC pattern. `PokerTableView` has a delegate and a datasource that `PokerViewController` implements.

I add a bunch of `CardView`s to the `PokerTableView`, and I want to move them around, so I add gesture recognizers within `CardView` class, and then add a delegate so each card can tell its parent (`PokerTableView`) that its being moved, tapped, etc.

Is this bad design?

What if `CardView` has subviews with delegates? Is it bad design to setup protocols in a grandparent, parent, child relationship?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Could please explain better your goal? Thanks.

Comment: Are you adding the CardView as UITableView's cell's contentView and have you subclassed UITableView to create PokerTableView?

Comment: I going to go out on a limb and guess that `PokerTableView` is just a `UIView` with a name that sounds like a `UITableView` subclass.  Right?  In that case, there's nothing, _prima facie_ that violates the general principles of MVC when a subview delegates to a superview in this way.

Comment: Yes, PokerTableView is just a regular UIView, bad naming conv. for stackoverflow... @NSBum, please submit your comment as an answer and I will approve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing - on the face of it - that breaks the general principles of MVC here.  In fact, the delegate pattern is well-known in the UIKit framework.

I think that the important thing here is to be very clear - both in your mind and in documentation - what object is responsible for what behavior and make sure those responsibilities make sense vis-a-vis the object's concept.  For example, `CardView` objects should be responsible for things that the visual representation of a card does.  `PokerTableView` objects should be responsible for the things that a visual representation of a poker table does.  Perhaps there are model classes behind the scenes, too.